# can't call Alamofire.request(...)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

This is my Pod file...

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.2'

target 'Karaweik' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire'
  # Pods for Karaweik

end
```

**And I only get call AlamofireVersionNumber:**

[image]

Comment: That's normal (which should not happen), but just type full code for Alamofire request and it will work.

Comment: @la-win-ko : Best thing you can do is after writing import statement just clean and build the project once to make the imported library available to project

Comment: @sharadchauhan , you are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an issue regarding this library, but if you add the required code it will work. Add this code for Alamofire and run :

```
Alamofire.request("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").responseData { (response) -> Void in

       let responseJson = String(data : response.result.value!, encoding : String.Encoding.utf8)
       print(responseJson)
 }
```